# Parse a line of pairs of delimited string and construct new command

Tags: shell, awk, openscad

I have this line as one of many in a file

```
show = "holder";  // [holder: Dispensor,dryer: Hair Dryer,bidet: Bedit,cover: Cover,wall mount: Wall Mount,screwdriver cutout: Screwdriver Cutout, assembly: Assembly,exploded: Exploded,vitamin: Vitamin]
```

What I want is to generate a shell script file where for each xxx:yyy pair generate the following line:

```
openscad --quite --export-format --D 'show=xxx' binstl -o xxx.stl $1
```

The $1 above is for the first parameter of a shell script.

I have tried this code:

```
match($0, /\[[^\n\]]*\]$/) {                # get [xx:yy, aa:bb]
    s = substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-2);    # strip the [ and ]
    n = split(s, arr,",");                  # split the pairs
    for(x in arr) {                         # for each pair
        match(arr[x], /([^\n:]+)/, b) {     # get the first field of the pair
            print subsgtr(b[1], RSTART, RLENGTH)
        }
    }
}
```

With this result:

```
gawk: prog:5:       match(arr[x], /([^\n:]+)/, b) {     # get the first field of the pair
gawk: prog:5:                                     ^ syntax error
```

I've also tried this:

```
    match($0, /\[[^\n\]]*\]$/) {                # get [xx:yy, aa:bb]
        s = substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-2);    # strip the [ and ]
        n = split(s, arr,",");                  # split the pairs
        for(x in arr) {                         # for each pair
            arr[x] ~ /([^\n:]+)/ print 
        }
    }

gawk: prog:5:       arr[x] ~ /([^\n:]+)/ print 
gawk: prog:5:                            ^ syntax error
```

and this:

```
match($0, /\[[^\n\]]*\]$/) {                # get [xx:yy, aa:bb]
    s = substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-2);    # strip the [ and ]
    n = split(s, arr,",");                  # split the pairs
    for(x in arr) {                         # for each pair
        arr[x] ~ /([^\n:]+)/ { print }
    }
}

gawk: prog:5:       arr[x] ~ /([^\n:]+)/ { print }
gawk: prog:5:                            ^ syntax error
```

I don't understand why I'm getting the syntax errors. If you show me a different/better solution, if you can, please explain the syntax errors so I can learn more about awk. Thanks!

Comment: the first `match` is the pattern of a pattern-action pair. the second `match` is not. it (or the `~`) needs to be wrapped in an `if`

Comment: you can pass the entire key value as a string and can use grep

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] we can copy/paste to test with. You're unlikely to get the best answer with 1 line of sample input, no expected output, and just a few lines of a script instead of a whole script. For example, having `\n` in your regexps is either a mistake and we don't know what it should be instead, or your RS is set to some value other than newline but we don't know what that value is and so again we don't know what your regexps should be to accommodate that.

Comment: Shouldn't you be trying to generate `openscad ... "$1"` (quoted) instead of `openscad -... $1` (unquoted)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` pattern-action statements are expressed as `condition {action}`. You cannot use the same pattern-action form inside an action. Use `if` statements, instead. For instance, replace `arr[x] ~ /([^\n:]+)/ print` with `if(arr[x] ~ /([^\n:]+)/) print`.

For your problem, and with the given example, you could define the input field separator as a regular expression, and skip the first and last fields. Example, with quotes added compared with the expected output (because you have some spaces there), and 2 typos fixed (`quiet` and `--export-format binstl`):

```
$ cmd="openscad --quiet --export-format binstl --D 'show=X' -o 'X.stl' \"\$1\""
$ awk -F '[[:space:]]*(.*[[]|:[^,]*[],])[[:space:]]*' -v cmd="$cmd" '
  {for(i = 2; i < NF; i++) {c=cmd; gsub(/X/,$i,c); print c}}' file
openscad --quiet --export-format binstl --D 'show=holder' -o 'holder.stl' "$1"
openscad --quiet --export-format binstl --D 'show=dryer' -o 'dryer.stl' "$1"
openscad --quiet --export-format binstl --D 'show=bidet' -o 'bidet.stl' "$1"
openscad --quiet --export-format binstl --D 'show=cover' -o 'cover.stl' "$1"
openscad --quiet --export-format binstl --D 'show=wall mount' -o 'wall mount.stl' "$1"
openscad --quiet --export-format binstl --D 'show=screwdriver cutout' -o 'screwdriver cutout.stl' "$1"
openscad --quiet --export-format binstl --D 'show=assembly' -o 'assembly.stl' "$1"
openscad --quiet --export-format binstl --D 'show=exploded' -o 'exploded.stl' "$1"
openscad --quiet --export-format binstl --D 'show=vitamin' -o 'vitamin.stl' "$1"
```

Note: another approach would be to write a generic bash script in which you use `awk` to feed a loop. In the following example the input file is passed as second parameter (`$2`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if (( $# != 2 )); then
  printf 'usage: %s ARG FILE\n' "${0##*/}"
  exit 1
elif ! [[ -f "$2" ]]; then
  printf '%s: file not found\n' "$2"
  exit 1
fi
awk -F '[[:space:]]*(.*[[]|:[^,]*[],])[[:space:]]*' '
  {for(i = 2; i < NF; i++) print $i}' "$2" | while read -r s; do
  openscad --quiet --export-format binstl --D "show=$s" -o "$s.stl" "$1"
done
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I was able to make that work with some modifications so I can exclude some of the items.

Answer (score 1):

Would this approach work?

Example data:

```
cat test.txt
show = "holder";  // [holder: Dispensor,dryer: Hair Dryer,bidet: Bedit,cover: Cover,wall mount: Wall Mount,screwdriver cutout: Screwdriver Cutout, assembly: Assembly,exploded: Exploded,vitamin: Vitamin]
```

Potential solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    FS = "[,:]"
}

{
    gsub(/^.*\[/, "", $1)
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i += 2) {
        sub("^ ", "", $i)
        out = $i
        sub(" ", ".", out)
        print "openscad --quite --export-format --D \047show=" $i "\047 binstl -o " out ".stl \"$1\""
    }
}' test.txt
openscad --quite --export-format --D 'show=holder' binstl -o holder.stl "$1"
openscad --quite --export-format --D 'show=dryer' binstl -o dryer.stl "$1"
openscad --quite --export-format --D 'show=bidet' binstl -o bidet.stl "$1"
openscad --quite --export-format --D 'show=cover' binstl -o cover.stl "$1"
openscad --quite --export-format --D 'show=wall mount' binstl -o wall.mount.stl "$1"
openscad --quite --export-format --D 'show=screwdriver cutout' binstl -o screwdriver.cutout.stl "$1"
openscad --quite --export-format --D 'show=assembly' binstl -o assembly.stl "$1"
openscad --quite --export-format --D 'show=exploded' binstl -o exploded.stl "$1"
openscad --quite --export-format --D 'show=vitamin' binstl -o vitamin.stl "$1"
```